# How test which HTML element I get back in Cypress without using class selectors?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, automated-tests, cypress

I'm trying to determine if an element selected by cypress is a "p-inputmask" or a "input" it would all be fine if I could use hasClass() but I cannot. Here is my current code:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('textInputWithLabelTest', (inputId,isDisabled,expectedLabel) => {
    let mask = false;
    cy.get(`[for="${inputId}"]`).should('contain',expectedLabel);
    cy.get(`#${inputId}`).then( ($el) => {
        cy.log($el.find('.ng-pristine'));
        console.log($el.find('p-inputmask')); //TODO fix this

    })
    if(mask) {
        cy.get(`#${inputId}`).siblings('input').should(isDisabled?'be.disabled':'not.be.disabled');
    } else {
        cy.get(`#${inputId}`).should(isDisabled?'be.disabled':'not.be.disabled');
    }
})
```

I tried JSON.stringify() with includes('p-inputmask') but the object is circular and it cannot be parsed.

I tried Jquery.toString() but jQuery doesn't want to be in the file for some reason even if I import it like : const `$ = require( "jquery" )( window );`

I tried it with .it('p-inputmask') it didn't work.

I tried it with .find('p-inputmask') and for some reason this returns a value even if the $el doesn't have a p-inputmask.

I tried it with .has(), it didn't work.

I tried all of these with both $el[0] and $el, nothing worked.

Here is what console.log($el[0]); outputs for the two different elements.

[image: input and inputmask console outputs]

There must be a trivial solution to this, but what? Could someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) property.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('textInputWithLabelTest', (inputId,isDisabled,expectedLabel) => {
  cy.get(`[for="${inputId}"]`).should('contain',expectedLabel);
  cy.get(`#${inputId}`).then($el => {

    if($el[0].tagName === 'INPUT') {
      cy.get(`#${inputId}`).should(isDisabled ? 'be.disabled' : 'not.be.disabled')
    } else {
      cy.get(`#${inputId}`)
        .siblings('input')
        .should(isDisabled ? 'be.disabled' : 'not.be.disabled')
    }
  })
})
```

I reversed the order of your if-else because I know an `<input>` has a `tagName` of `INPUT`, but I'm not sure about the other element. You can experiment with what I've shown.

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution, but it doesn't work because of some cypress weirdness, which is okay, I'll try to work around it  because this is answers my question, and it should work if cypress was less weird when working with if statements.